# Are you sure pop up using in an ejs page

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have an ejs view that is looping through a number of orders and displaying them on the page.
I have a delete link that passes the id of the record that has been click as part of the route that then deletes the order from a mongoDB
Thats all working, however I want to add in a popup that asks the user if they are sure they want to delete the record first and im not sure how i should best go about it.
I know about the confirm() method, but im not sure how i get that to work within an ejs page that is looping through records and still get it to pick just the one I click on.

```
<% orders.forEach(function(orders){ %>            
                <a href="/deleteOrder/<%=orders._id%>" class="card-link">Cancel Order</a>                   
        <%})%>
```

Comment: To implement the prompt client-side, a delete button or link or whatever would typically call some client-side Javascript and that Javascript would either use `confirm()` or temporarily insert an HTML prompt into the page itself.  Your template would insert the delete button and the code to make it call the client-side Javascript and that client-side Javascript would then be in some script accessible in that page.  All the buttons can access the same script.  After the prompt confirmation, you would THEN run the `/deleteOrder` request (probably via a Javascript Ajax call).

Comment: @jfriend00 ok so do i have to do anything special to handle the fact that the link is within a loop and i only want to delete the decord that is clicked on?

Comment: Yes, when you generate the code from the link that calls the Javascript function to prompt the deletion, it needs to pass some sort of ID for what you're trying to delete so when that Javascript gets a confirmation from the user and then wants to carry out the deletion, it knows how to specify the right item.

Comment: AH OK so if i create a function called deleteOrder and call it as deleteOrder(<%=orders._id%>) then it should pass the correct ID to the function?
How do open a page using a route (ie /deleteOrder/:id ) rather than a full url?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea for calling the function.  I don't know what you mean by "open a page".

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry I might have not used the right wording. I mean how do i use javascript on the client side to load a webpage base on its server route, in this case /deleteOrder/:id rather than a full URL (eg http// ect). 
If i was to do it on the server side using express I would use res.redirect("/deleteOrder/:id") but i am not sure for client side